# Java apns : list of device tokens under an application

Tags: java, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Am trying to create a java project which can able to send push notification to iPad/iPhone devices. By giving a static list of device tokens i can able  to send push notifications using this java application.

But what i want is, i need to get a list of device tokens of devices those installed the same app. So is there any way to get a list of device tokens that are tied under an application.??

Any suggestions on this will be appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APNS generates device tokens based on device certificates and keeps track of them. But, you cannot ask APNS for a list of tokens.

Just after a token is generated by APNS, it is sent back to the app. Your app is responsible to forward the token to your server. You must store this list of tokens yourself on your server. You can later use this list to send notifications via APNS.